# p7zip / unzip case sensitivity - extracts archive to seperate folders

Tags: unzip, centos6, 7zip

I am supplied data by a third party company in the form of self extracting EXE archives.

Take example:

```
fvdata.exe
```

When i extract this archive on my windows machine I get this(this is what I am trying to achieve):

```
fvdata_d
```

however on my CentOS 6.5 machine I get two folders:

```
fvdata_d FVdata_d
```

I believe the tech putting this archive together was a bit sloppy when it came to their case sensitivity. However I am not sure how to fix this.

Commands I have tried on the linux machine to extract:

```
7za x fvdata.exe -y -ssc- 

unzip fvdata.exe -C

unzip fvdata.exe
```

If I can't do this maybe someone can reccommend a work around?

Comment: So to be clear: you need both folders, each with their own unique set of files?

Comment: i need the contents of both folders but in one folder: fvdata_d, the way that it extracts on the windows machine.

Comment: So (trying to wring out the problem) currently it extracts one folder but nothing from the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In unzip, the -LL option forces conversion of every filename to lowercase, regardless of the originating file system.

http://www.info-zip.org/mans/unzip.html

Comment: Thanks! My bad the -LL option wasnt listed in the -h it was in the -hh.

Comment: answered! can't upvote yet but i will when rep is up. Thanks again